# How to perform an action when a customer dialog box is closed in Android Studio?

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

I am changing a text of a label when the dialog box opens via a button click, what I also want to do is change the text back when the dialog box closes. I do not have any buttons on the dialog and by default user is able to press the back key or tap anywhere outside of the dialog box to close it. (I do not want to add a button). I have been trying for to work this out for a good day now and still for the life of me figure out how it works (Shows what a newbie I am!) I have tried various methods e.g.

1. if(dialog.isShowing() != true) label2.setText = "Well done"

but none seems to work, I understand the solution may be simple... I have tried stuff like dismiss etc. too.

I will really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Customdialog=new Dialog(this);
    Customdialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        //code you want to execute when the dialog is closed 
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps (:

Comment: Thanks that worked, I tried the exact same thing before but it wasn't working maybe I missed something, or your input was required!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an onDismissListener() to set as listener whenever the dialog is closed

Comment: I have already tried but not sure where to add the onDismissListerner and how to add it. Is it where I create the dialog box or in a seperate method etc.